# How to determine the Server Name of a SQL Server with a T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server

I want to know if there is a T-SQL statement that returns the Server name of a SQL Server.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to know the instance name of SQL Server, the actual physical computer name (e.g. in a cluster), or something else? "Server" is ambiguous in this context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is as follows:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Another way:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
```

Answer (score 17):

This will give the actual physical machine name (e.g. in case of a cluster) as well as the server\instance name:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS'), @@SERVERNAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @@servername
```

[MSDN @@servername](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx)